# Setup google test with Mingw64 on windows 10 (C language)

Tags: c, unit-testing, window, googletest

I'm using Google test to test C code on Windows, but some problems happen when I do that. I have already installed Cmake, MingW64, python and set path for installed packages within Environment Variablest.Then I download https://github.com/google/googletest example and follow the guildline to run it.

The steps like this:

```
1. Open cmd on windows
2. cd xxx/googletest-master/googletest
3. cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" CMakeLists.txt
```

The result like this:

```
C:\Users\TIEN\Desktop\UNITTEST\googletest-master\googletest>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" CMakeLists.txt
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:54 (project):
  VERSION keyword not followed by a value or was followed by a value that
  expanded to nothing.


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/python.exe (found version "2.7.8")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest
```

```
4. mingw32-make.exe
```

The result like this:

```
C:\Users\TIEN\Desktop\UNITTEST\googletest-master\googletest>mingw32-make.exe
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/type_traits:35:0,
                 from C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:59,
                 from C:\Users\TIEN\Desktop\UNITTEST\googletest-master\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:38:
C:/PROGRA~2/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40:0,
                 from C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:62,
                 from C:\Users\TIEN\Desktop\UNITTEST\googletest-master\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:38:
C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:972:1: error: identifier 'nullptr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
 inline void FlushInfoLog() { fflush(nullptr); }
 ^
C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:2104:1: error: identifier 'constexpr' is a keyword in C++11 [-Werror=c++0x-compat]
 constexpr BiggestInt kMaxBiggestInt = (std::numeric_limits<BiggestInt>::max)();
 ^
In file included from C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:62:0,
                 from C:\Users\TIEN\Desktop\UNITTEST\googletest-master\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:38:
........................................................
........................................................
C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest.cc: At global scope:
C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest.cc:189:14: error: 'FILE* testing::internal::OpenFileForWriting(const string&)' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
 static FILE* OpenFileForWriting(const std::string& output_file) {
              ^
C:/Users/TIEN/Desktop/UNITTEST/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest.cc:357:13: error: 'bool testing::internal::GTestIsInitialized()' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
 static bool GTestIsInitialized() { return GetArgvs().size() > 0; }
             ^
cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:76: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

It happen errors and can not run google test, How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is off-topic here. You need to ask a more specific question on an obstacle you encountered when trying ot adapt tutorial examples to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I have already added the issue clearly

Comment: Please turn your pictures of text into text, which is much preferred here on StackOverflow (assuming that I did not miss some relevant detail only carried by pictures).

Comment: Please make a [mre] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compile as c++.

Comment: I am try running google test example, maybe is c++

Comment: Everyone know way to fix it ?.Please,help me